# Collapse HTML if no content found

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to be able to remove HTML elements if they contain no content.

Let's say we have some markup and are targeting all '`collapse`' classes:

```
<div class='collapse'>[CONTENT?]</div>
```

If there is some content then don't do anything.

But if there is no content - no string characters or whitespace - then remove the div element completely.

This is easy to implement in the simple cases but with nested content it's slightly more more tricky.

Here is a demo, if you try removing the [CONTENTX?] strings and then seeing what the HTML structure is you'll notice that it doesn't work completely.

If a div only has other divs with no content then that should be treated as no characters or whitespace.

If we remove all [CONTENTX?] strings then we should see no HTML structure.

What ways are there to handle this?

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/97udq/

HTML:

```
<div id='container'>

    <div class='collapse'>
    [CONTENT1?]    
    </div>

    <div class='collapse'>
        [CONTENT2?]    
        <div class='collapse'>
            [CONTENT3?]    
            <div class='collapse'>[CONTENT4?]</div>
            <div class='collapse'>[CONTENT5?]</div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
    // function
    collapse();
    // Show HTML structure
    alert($('#container').html());
});

function collapse(){
    // Loop thru all collapse elements
    $('.collapse').each(function(){
        // Check for pure whitespace
        if($(this).html().replace(/\s+/g, '').length==0){
            // Nothing to see, so remove.
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
}
```

CSS:

```
.collapse{
    height:20px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: And you can't change the HTML at all? If you can, I would recommend wrapping the contents in their own divs.

Comment: @bfavaretto How would wrapping the contents with another div solve the puzzle?

Comment: It wouldn't solve the puzzle, but would simplify targeting the content and the nested blocks separately. Anyway, I liked the accepted solution, it's simple enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [this](http://jsfiddle.net/97udq/1/) does the job;

It just uses `text()` instead of `html()`;

Here's the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

[This one](http://jsfiddle.net/97udq/2) adds the trim(), but I thik that's not what you want.

```
function collapse(){
    $('.collapse').each(function(){
        if($(this).text().length==0){
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: No. only the text gets removed. As per your fiddle.

Comment: The 2 divs after `[Content3?]` does get removed. Or maybe I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Answer content should be _within_ the answer.

Comment: This answer is basically correct, it just needs the content from the `trim()` fiddle copied so it appears as part of the StackOverlow answer. Using `RegExp` rather than `trim` might be more supported...

Comment: Thank you for showing me the text function. I'll check it to see if it works in this case.

Comment: @Johnny5 The trim function I also need to check for pure whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way of accomplishing what you want. It recurses down the DOM pruning nodes from the bottom up. Hope this helps.

```
    function prune(root) {
       $.each($(root).children(), function(){
          prune($(this));
       });
       if($(root).html().replace(/\s+/g, '').length==0 && $(root).hasClass("collapse")){
          $(root).detach();
       }
   }
```

[Code integrated into your JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/97udq/11/)

Comment: Nice answer using recursion.

Answer (score 1):

You need to recreate the `.each()` loop, but reversed. Just like that :

```
function collapse(){
    var el = $('.collapse');
    for(var i = el.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        if(el[i].innerHTML.replace(/\s+/g, '').length==0){
            $(el[i]).remove();
        }
    }
}
```

It will remove the childrens first, then check for parent.

Here a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/97udq/5/

---

**EDIT :**

I missunderstood your question, here's the right solution :

```
function collapse(){
    $('.collapse').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this)
        var clone = $this.clone();
        clone.children().remove();
        if(clone.html().replace(/\s+/g, '').length==0){
            $this.children().appendTo($this.parent());
            $this.remove()
        }
    })
}
```

Basicly, you clone the current div, remove its children and then check if there is some text. If there's none, you append his children to his parent

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/97udq/9/

Comment: Not working. If the last element is present. It shows 2 blank rows, then value in the 3rd.

Comment: That's not what the OP want?

Comment: I did, I didnt said that what you said was wrong, I asked if I missunderstanded the question...

Comment: If you use below as HTML, it still shows an empty row..              <div id='container'>

    <div class='collapse'>content</div>
        
    <div class='collapse'>a  
        <div class='collapse'>a
            <div class='collapse'></div>
            <div class='collapse'>content</div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

Comment: Are you on the second fiddle? Because it work for me : http://jsfiddle.net/97udq/12/. Can you update the fiddle so i can see what you mean? I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work but I prefer the simpler methods that don't use cloning of objects.